# What happened to Children of Prince Halil of Ottoman Empire?

Tags: byzantine-empire, ottoman-empire, royalty, turkey, genealogy

Inspired from [my discussion with MA Goulding](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/35783/where-are-the-descendants-of-mughals-today/35790?noredirect=1#comment92562_35790) on Byzantine-Ottoman blood ties, I am curious about something.

Shehzade [Halil Orhanoghlu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Eehzade_Halil) was son of [Orhan I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orhan) of Ottoman Sultanate and Princess [Theodora Kantakouzene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodora_Kantakouzene,_wife_of_Orhan) of Byzantine Empire.

Halil went on to marry his first cousin, Princess [Irene Palaiologina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_V_Palaiologos#Family), daughter of Emperor John V Palailogos and sister of Andronikos IV.

Wikipedia says that the Prince Halil had two sons:

1. Shehzade Gunduz Osmanlı
2. Shehzade Omer Osmanlı

There is no mention of this junior line (Gunduz and Omer's) of House of Osman anywhere else. Wiki also gives them titles of [Bey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bey) so I am assuming that their grandfather Orhan or uncle Murad I arranged some lands for them to hold?

TL;DR, Do we know of their fate or their descendants? Could they have fled to Byzantine Empire where their maternal uncles ruled when their father Prince Halil's rebellion failed? If not, did they play any role in Byzantine-Ottoman relations as Greeks may have been more willing to trust these Princelings rather than other Ottomans in diplomacy as they were half Greeks themselves? I know if I were Murad I and had half-Greek nephews with claims to the throne of ERE, I would use them to full extent; For diplomacy and blackmailing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a book *The Structure of the Ottoman Dynasty* Anthony Dolphin Alderson, 1956, 1982 that gives very complete and I hope accurate genealogical information about Ottoman genealogy.

Not having access to it, I tried this website:

http://web.archive.org/web/20060426191440/http://www.4dw.net/royalark/Turkey/turkey2.htm[1](http://web.archive.org/web/20060426191440/http://www.4dw.net/royalark/Turkey/turkey2.htm)

It merely says when the sons of Prince Halil were born.

Since Wikipedia says that Prince Halil was killed by his brother Murad in 1362, it is possible that his two sons were also killed in 1362.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the book. I hope I can find it. Yeah I did see that Halil was killed when his second son was born and first one was just 1 or 2 years old but while Fratrecide was common in Ottomans, killing babies seems kinda unlikely. Don't forget wiki also gives them the titles of Bey (Not effendi or celebi as usual). So that kinda implies that they probably survived their father's fall from grace